# Ocultar una etiqueta div en HTML

Tags: html

Tengo el siguinete codigo:

```html
<div class="auto" id="auto">
  Ocultar
</div>
```

Me podrian decir si la etiqueta  tiene alguna propiedad para ocultar.

Comment: quieres que la etiqueta div se oculte? en que momento? desde que carga el DOM o cuando se le de click?

Comment: Es dependiendo de la situacion, con saber si es posible que con una propiedad de la etiqueta se pueda ocultar es mas que suficioente, gracias

Comment: hecho @ARR y de paso una recomendación te dejé

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Con el estilo "display: none" puedes ocultarla

```html
<div class="auto" id="auto" style="display: none">
  Oculta
</div>

 <div class="auto" id="auto">
  No Oculta
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Con el atributo hidden directo desde CSS se puede lograr

```
<style>
  /*
   Los estilos puedes ponerlos al inicio de tu documento HTML o puedes 
   meterlos en un archivo por separado
  */
  .auto{
   display: none;
 }
</style>
<div class="auto" id="auto">
  Ocultar
</div>
```

> Trata siempre que tu código CSS no quede mezclado con tu HTML pues lo
>   vuelve poco mantnible en cuanto crezca tu proyecto

Si decides meter tu código CSS en un archivo externo coloca la etiqueta para invocarlo después de tu última etiqueta meta en la parte superior, deberá quedarte mas o menos así

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="carpeta/archivo.css" />
```

Lo anterior te lo recomiendo para evitar que cuando retomes el proyecto o alguien mas participe se vuelva compleja y dificil el proceso de hacer modificaciones

Answer (score 3):

Primero debemos de tener nuestra esturara HTML donde existirá un botón que activara una función JavaScript que hará el cambio del CSS para mostrar el efecto.
en este caso el boton sera un div

```js
var clic = 1;
function divAuto(){ 
   if(clic==1){
   document.getElementById("div-mostrar").style.height = "100px";
   clic = clic + 1;
   } else{
    document.getElementById("div-mostrar").style.height = "0px";      
    clic = 1;
   }   
}
```

```css
Después de tener estos dos div utilice algo de CSS3 para darle el diseño y logar el efecto de transición.

#auto{
 padding: 10px;
 background: orange;
 width: 95px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
 display: inline-block;
}

#auto:hover{
 opacity: .8;
}

#div-mostrar{
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 0px;
 background: #000;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 3px #D8D8D8;
 transition: height .4s;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}
#auto:hover{
 opacity: .8;
}
#auto:hover + #div-mostrar{
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="auto" onclick="divAuto()">
Mostrar/Ocultar
</div>
<div id="div-mostrar">
DIV
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="auto" id="auto" style="visibility: hidden">
  Oculta
</div>
```

aunque esto hace lo que quieres, deberías evitar a toda costa usar "estilos en linea" para este tipo de cosas la mejor manera seria usando CSS desde un archivo externo y cambiando las propiedades usando JavaScript

Comment: Deberías explicar un poco más tu respuesta.

Comment: Digamos que usas 3 cosas en una web HTML, CSS y JS. cada una de estas tiene un proposito. el HTML por ejemplo. Es la estructura de tu web, el CSS es para los estilos, (colores, tamaños, tipo de letra) y el JavaScript es para la funcionalidad, digamos que en un principio tienes una etiqueta HTML oculta, y que con un click en un botón la etiqueta aparece... pues en ese caso con HTML agregas la etiqueta, con CSS la ocultas, y con JS la haces aparecer dinamicamente. Te dejo un link, ojala te sea de utilidad... https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-css-inline-style-3466446

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi solución amigo:

```html
<div class="auto" id="auto" style="display:none;">
  Ocultar
</div>
```